# How do I get attributes from relationship-related entity in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity, relationship, nsfetchrequest

I'm experienced with ObjC, but relatively new to Core Data.  Until now, it's been pretty straightforward, but I'm a little stuck with relationships, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have two entities: one is a list of people, and the other is a list of events.

I've set up an inverse relationship (called 'people') in the data model between the two entities, with the People side set as 'to-many.'  In other words, I could have 5 people but thousands of events; each event is tied to a single person, but a single person could be responsible for any number of events.

I add events using [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName...], and then retrieve them with an NSFetchedResultsController.

Problem is that I haven't yet successfully been able to retrieve the data about a person when fetching a particular event object.  Example:

```
Log *logEntry = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// this works:

NSLog(@"description: %@", logEntry.description);
NSLog(@"happened %i minutes ago", -[logEntry.date timeIntervalSinceNow] / 60);

// this does not (just spits out NULL):

NSLog(@"person responsible: %@", logEntry.people.name);
```

What am I missing?  How do I get the data about the person in the relationship?  I have a feeling I've left out an important link when adding the log entries in the first place, or perhaps a necessary predicate when retrieving the log entries.  Apple's docs are a bit scant when it comes to relationships and specific examples.  I may still have my head stuck in old-school SQL here, so I can really use some help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If people is multiple people, then it would come back as a set - so logEntry.people returns an NSSet of people, which you would have to loop over to get out People and thus be able to ask for Names of the people.

Any relationship with more than one object gets modeled as a set (currently in iOS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As stated above, an event should be tied to a single person.  Is logEntry.people returned as an NSSet if there's only one record?  BTW, I have tried this, but when I cast it as an NSSet, the set is empty.  I suspect there's either a missing predicate or perhaps I am inserting the record incorrectly. Any more thoughts?

Comment: If you have an inverse relationship setting an event on a person, should also set people on an event.  You claim there is only one person possible, but if so why is the relationship named "people" - to me that indicates the relationship is to-many.

Comment: It's called "people" for consistency with the rest of the app, and to differentiate it from "person" which I use to identify a single record in the "people" entity. Since the data I'm getting is empty, I figure that either the fetch request is bad, or the data is incomplete.  If there's nothing more to the fetch request than what I've already included, then the data must be bad.  What I'm not understanding is how, exactly, I'm supposed to associate a single event with a single single person from the people entity.

Comment: On a side note, that terminology is really confusing, to the point where I'm not sure I understand the model anymore. Can you isolate that segment of the model and produce a screenshot?  The simple answer to the way you'd associate a single event with a person is to just say even.person = person, where you'd extract a specific person from people (unless people is person, which again is really confusing me).

Comment: Sorry for the confusing nomenclature - I'll rethink that.  Anyway, I've figured out the problem.  Turns out I wasn't assigning a valid object to event.person when the new event was added to the db.  It wasn't a fetch issue at all.  For those following this, you just need to retrieve a valid object from the related entity, hold onto it (in an array or whatever) long enough to refer to it when using insertNewObjectForEntityForName.  Thanks for your help, Kendall!